# InnoSetup (sha1 + base64 encoding a string)

Tags: base64, inno-setup, pascal, sha1

Is there a way I can encode a password using sha1 and then base64 the output in InnoSetUp?

I see InnoSetup already has `GetSHA1OfString()`, but this is not base64 encoded but is a hexadecimal encoding.

I found someone posted a function here
http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Encode/Decode_Base64

But this just takes an ANSI string as input, so I cant pass the output of `GetSHA1OfString()` to this.

I want to do base64 encoding of input say `admin` using sha1, so output should be
`0DPiKuNIrrVmD8IUCuw1hQxNqZc=`

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance !!

Comment: Also asked on the [Inno newsgroups](http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=97067&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#97067)

Answer (score 0):

FPC comes with sha1 and base64 libraries, so you can write your own function (could be implemented in one line, but I've splitted it into 3 to add comments):

```pascal
uses
  sha1,
  base64;

function GetBase64SHA1OfString(const S: AnsiString): AnsiString;
var
  Digest: TSHA1Digest;
  DigestStr: AnsiString;
begin
  // Compute the SHA1
  Digest := SHA1String(S);
  // Convert SHA1 to string representation
  DigestStr := SHA1Print(Digest);
  // Compute base64 of the string representation and return it
  Exit(EncodeStringBase64(DigestStr));
end;

begin
  Writeln(GetBase64SHA1OfString('Hello!'));
end.
```